# Using Signal in asp.net core without using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, signalr

I work in a small company where I have been given a old asp.net core 2.2 project, built with helix architecture.

I have been tasked with using SignalR to create push notifications. Therefore, I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) guide for trying to set up signalR.
I have added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` dependency to the project, and added this line to `RegisterDependencies`:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

My current initialization file now looks like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization.Services;
using Seges.SC.Foundation.ApplicationInitialization.Initialization;

namespace Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization.Initialization
{
    [SuppressMessage(
        "UnusedCode",
        "CA1812:Never instantiated",
        Justification = "Instantiated through reflection/dependency injection")]
    [SuppressMessage(
        "ReSharper",
        "UnusedMember.Global",
        Justification = "Instantiated through reflection/dependency injection")]
    internal class PersonalizationInitializer : BaseApplicationInitializer
    {
        public override string Name => nameof(PersonalizationInitializer);

        public override void RegisterDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
            services.AddSignalRCore();
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that in the usual examples of setting this up, the following code is needed in the `configuration` function:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapHub(“/NotificationHub”);
});
```

So my issue is regarding getting acces to the `app` object, which usually is in `IApplicationBuilder` form.
I tried just doing this by adding a nuget reference to `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` and then importing it. But when I look for packages with nuget of that name, nothing shows up:

searching for the package:
[image]

So, is there any way that I can perform this setup step, without needing to access `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`, or am I maybe looking for the dependency in a wrong way?

Comment: Don't you have a `Configure` method in your `Startup`? There is no nuget for `IApplicationBuilder` because it is a part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`

Comment: ah cool, so i just need to install  ``Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` thats great

Comment: I bet you already have one in you API/MVC project. You only need to find the appropriate place for applying that method (in Startup class)